# After Setting up my Bitcoin core Server, I need to create wallets for each of my client on a website may be thousands

Tags: bitcoin-core

After Setting up my Bitcoin core Server, I need to create wallets for each of my client on a website may be thousands. 
How can i generate wallets on per user basis that if bitcoin core does not allow me.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to create wallets for each of my client on a website may be thousands

There are several ways to generate addresses in bulk. Using Bitcoin Core exclusively you can create individual wallets with the `createwallet` command in the RPC and then create new address with [`getnewaddress`](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#getnewaddress) although you will have to do this programmatically as there is no built-in functionality for the creation of X number of addresses at a time.

A faster alternative outside of Bitcoin Core would be to use a vanity address generator such as [VanityGen](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Vanitygen). The initial intention of VanityGen was to allow for the creation of unique/custom addresses with specified prefixed characters otherwise known as "vanity" addresses. Luckily this tool has an array of command-line parameters useful for bulk addresses generation too. VanityGen utilizes your graphics card (OpenCL-compatible) making it significantly more powerful than the standard CPU generation found in the Bitcoin Core client. Similarly, it works both online and offline.

Using the 64-bit Windows binaries provided on the [project's GitHub](https://github.com/samr7/vanitygen), I can use the following command-line options:

```
vanitygen64 -o key_pairs.txt -v -k 1
```

`-o` Specifies file to write key pair to (Pattern, Address, PrivateKey)

`-v` Makes output verbose (Provides Pattern, PublicKey, PrivateKey, Address in stdout)

`-k` Continues search after finding a match (run infinitely until exited)

`1` This is what the vanity generator will look for as a prefix.

All of the generated addresses and their private keys will be listed in the output file (`key_pairs.txt` in the example). You can parse this file and assign each of your "clients" a private and public key pair as well as the address that goes along with it.